# Display message box in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to compare two date columns in excel(vba). If the cell values are equal, a message box has to be displayed with "TARGET ACHIEVED", "YES" or "NO" option. Based on the value selected, 2nd column cell color has to be changed
 - YES - orange
 - NO  - blue

Answer (score 2):

Following code will do it.

```
Dim Date1 As String
Dim Date2 As String
Dim msgResult As VbMsgBoxResult

Date1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1)
Date2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2)

If IsDate(Date1) And IsDate(Date2) Then
    If CDate(Date1) = CDate(Date2) Then
        msgResult = MsgBox("TARGET ACHIEVED", vbYesNo)

        If vbYes = msgResult Then
            ' code for Yes handling
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 'orange
        Else
            ' code for NO handling
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'blue color
        End If
    End If
End If
```

You can get more Excel colour codes [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm).

Comment: The above code is working only for the first row, i need the same condition to be applicable for entire column. Eg: Column A and Column B, For each date entries in each of these columns cells, I need the comparison to be applied.

Comment: @ssneha: You just need to iterate over all rows of column A and B. You can do it by adding a for loop. To get the maximum rows of a column use code such as lRowCountA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @MNS: I tried with the above code, i am facing an issue. Suppose if the condition is applied for 10th row, for each row iteration message box is getting displayed, until it reached 10th row. I want to get it only for the 10th row.

Comment: @ssneha: You can apply whatever logic required. If you want the message to be displayed only for the 10th row then you can put the MsgBox() call and its related checking inside an if condition. That if condition should check whether the loop count variable has reached 10 or not.